# How many combinations are there for $(a,b,c)$ where $a, b, c$ are from the Natural numbers and $a < b < c < N$ for some chosen $N$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many combinations are there for $(a,b,c)$ where $a, b, c$ are from the Natural numbers and $a < b < c < N$ for some chosen $N$?

I wanted to see what's an elegant counting argument for this?

Comment: As can be seen from the answers below, there is an important subjective question for this problem: Do you consider $0$ a natural number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking here: what is the number of subsets of $\left\{ 0,\ldots,N-1\right\} $
that have exactly $3$ elements? The answer is $$\binom{N}{3}$$
In this answer $0$ is taken to be a natural number.

Answer (score 1):

$a<b<c$ means we are just taking three different numbers from $1,...,N-1$, so there are $\binom {N-1}{3}$ options.
(See [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) )

You need not divide by $3!$, since there is a strong inequality:
You may take $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$, but you can't take $(a,b,c)=(3,2,1)$.

Comment: But I think here the order matters. So one would have to divide by the possible permutations of (a,b,c), i.e, $3!$.

Comment: @LeoAzevedo added an explanation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Got mixed up with the concept of binomial coefficient.